# Scrapy, parse email in multiple sites

Tags: python, parsing, scrapy

I've got a question about parsing e-mail in various sites by means Scrapy.
I have such spider:

```py
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider

from sufio.items import MItem


class MSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'mparser'
    start_urls = [
        'https://horizonsupply.myshopify.com/pages/about-us',
        'https://fnatic-shop.myshopify.com/pages/about-us',
        'https://horizonsupply.myshopify.com/pages/about-us',
        'https://fnatic-shop.myshopify.com/pages/about-us'

    ]
    def parse(self, response):
        item = MItem()
        item['facebook'] = response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "facebook")]/@href').extract_first()
        item['twitter'] = response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "twitter")]/@href').extract_first()
#        item['email'] =
        yield item
```

I need to follow each link and check, if there is email. Is it possible to perform by means scrapy?

Comment: _if there is email_? can you explain more in deep your question?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma I meant, can I parse email from each sites by means regular expression or something like that. I cannot do that by means xpath, because it's different on each site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use something like this:

```
mails = response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "mailto:")]/@href').extract()
    mails += response.xpath('//*[not(self::script or self::style)]/text()[normalize-space(.)][contains(.,"@")] | '
                            '//a[contains(./@href,"@")]/@href').extract()
    for a in response.xpath('//a[contains(text(),"@")]'):
        ma = ''.join(a.xpath('./text()').extract())
        mails.append(ma)
```

But after this, i use additional function for remove duplicate and invalid rows.

Comment: I found another solution of this problem, I used bs4 and wrote something like that:
def parse_emails(soup):
    emails = []
    soup_regexp = soup.find_all(text=re.compile(r'(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)'))
    for email in soup_regexp:
        emails.append(email)
    return emails